# Certificate SAN Disclosure. How harmful can it be?

Tags: tls, aws, san

My daily job duties brought me (by mistake) to the following IP: 52.63.96.32

It appears the registrar has signed with a single certificate a "lot" of domain. https://www.shodan.io/host/52.63.96.32
[image]

Am am right to assume that:

- This is information leakage, it discloses websites that aren't
  advertised on search engines.
- The virtual web-servers all share the
  same VM The virtual web-servers all use the same certificate.
  therefore if the private key can be leaked/disclosed by one web
  server using an insecure SSL/TLS  protocol.
- Each customer should be concerned as this is potentially vulnerable to Meldown/Spectre ?

Also, If one of this website was to be compromised (Injection or XSS). Does it compromise other websites ?

And finally, Should I have any concerns if my company was hosting a website on this server ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it is perfectly normal for content delivery networks to have such certificates. And given the IP address this looks like Amazon AWS, possible their [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https.html) service which serves as a TLS termination point and load balancer which then forwards the traffic to the appropriate system. This is actually typical behavior which you will also see at Cloudflare CDN. Therefore I don't think that this was a mistake.

> This is information leakage, it discloses websites that aren't advertised on search engines.

I think that these sites have explicitly configured HTTPS access so that they get included in the certificate.

> The virtual web-servers all share the same VM The virtual web-servers all use the same certificate. therefore if the private key can be leaked/disclosed by one web server using an insecure SSL/TLS protocol.

This certificate is probably used at a load balancer which then forwards the requests to different sites which in case of Amazon AWS are probably each in their own VM.

> Each customer should be concerned as this is potentially vulnerable to Meldown/Spectre ?

No. Sharing the same TLS termination endpoint should not cause such problems.

> Also, If one of this website was to be compromised (Injection or XSS). Does it compromise other websites ?

XSS is not an attack against the server. Other injections like SQL injection can be. But given that these are probably independent sites running in their own VM a compromise of one VM does not compromise the other one.

> And finally, Should I have any concerns if my company was hosting a website on this server ?

No.